# How to validate the dropdown using asp.net so that one needs to select an option (even if it is seen as default) in order to proceed

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

In my form, I have a dropdown menu labelled Applications and it has 3 options L1, L2 and L3. When the webpage is loaded one sees L1 present by default (but not selected) in the dropdown. I wish that one should not be able to proceed without actually selecting what he/she wants. Even if a person wants L1 he/she needs to select it else person cannot proceed/submit the form. The values L1,L2 and L3 are coming from database. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

On page load, after binding dropdownlist, create an extra entry e.g. "Select".

```
if (!IsPostback) {
   YourDropdown.Items.Add(new ListItem("--Select--","0"));
   YourDropdown.Items.FindByValue("0").Selected = true;
}
```

On submit button, check if value is equal to zero. This canbe done throw Javascript/jQuery as well. Or check on server-side if `YourDropdown` value is not "0".

On ClientClick of submit button check value like:

```
if ($("#<%YourDropdown.ClientID%>").val()=="0") 
{
     alert('select a value');
     return false;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `protected void  btnAddNewGroup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lbgroup.Visible = true;
        lbgroupdesc.Visible = true;
        txtGroupName.Visible = true;
        txtGroupDescription.Visible = true;
        btnAddGroup.Visible = true;
        btnCancel.Visible = true;
        lbApplication.Visible = true;
        ddApplicationList.Visible = true;
      if ($("#<%ddApplicationList.ClientID%>").val()=="0") 
{
     Response.Write("<script>alert('Select a value');</script>");
    
} 
.
    }` I get an error unexpected symbol $. please pardon my silly questions

Comment: You are missing including jQuery file. Add jQuery file in <head> </head>

Comment: Ok. So I have 2 files one is a .aspx for front end and another is .aspx.cs for control backend. In which file should I add what? Please answer.

Comment: .aspx , inside <head> </head>